# Convert number of seconds to time

Tags: c++, datetime, time

Is there a way to convert the number of seconds (e.g. `3056144 sec`, this is time delta not a time) to time in format `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`?

I've tried to convert number of seconds to `struct tm` using `localtime` and then substract UNIX start time (1970-01-01), but this is not working as expected.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have to use C++03, not C++11.

Comment: How good does the solution have to be? Remember there have been a few leap seconds since 1970 and future leap seconds are not announced with much notice.

Comment: You really need to have a start reference time, otherwise the format YYYY-MM-- ... etc is invalid because when you say MM, is that a month with 28 days, or 29 days or 30 or 31 or 31 with an extra second (December with a leap second)?  If you have a reference date, you can use calendars, otherwise you can only guess (e.g. one month == exactly 30 days, one year == exactly 365 days).  The app may not care, but then why this particular format?

Comment: If it's a time **delta**, why are you even trying to convert it to an absolute date?

Answer (score 1):

If using [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time.html) is an option for you, this might be what you're looking for:

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

using boost::posix_time::seconds;
using boost::posix_time::to_simple_string;

std::cout << to_simple_string(seconds(3056144)) << std::endl;
```

This will print:

> 848:55:44

However, as you can see in the output above, it will not tell you how many years have passed. This is for good reason, because a year has not always 365 days.

Answer (score 0):

If you're converting a time delta to ISO 8601-like time, you just need to offset your timedelta by the number of seconds since 1907-01-01 that corresponds to your 0 (start) time, *then* use `localtime` to convert to a `struct tm`.

---

Due to the fact that the number of days per month depends on which month and year it is, trying to convert delta seconds to any larger time units than days *without considering where the start and end times are on the actual calendar* is going to be fraught with errors.

Like Bathsheba mentions, it depends on how accurate you need to be.

I've seen some algorithms duck the issue that simply assuming a month is 30 days (and therefore a year is only 360 days). If that's what you want to do, then trying to use `localtime` ill be more trouble than it's worth.

If you want to do it "exactly" right, you have to convert your start and end times to actual aligned-to-the-epoch `time_t` values, and use some kind of calendar-aware date computation to work out the time between the two. `localtime` isn't going to cut it (and that's not even considering how it would be an hour off id the timedelta crosses a DST boundary).

Comment: can't quiet understand what you mean. If I have timedelta set to 61 sec, then I should give `0000-00-00 00:01:01` and so on.

Comment: Take your start time (as a `time_t`) and add timedelta (integer number of seconds) to it *before* calling `localtime()`.  Then use the resulting `struct tm` or call `strftime()` on it.

Comment: @mark4o: I don't have any _start time_. I have time difference between time on two devices and I need convert this difference to the format I've mentioned.

Comment: @maverik: Oh I see.  If you don't have an absolute `time_t` then you could use `gmtime()` instead of `localtime()`.  But that is a weird format as the number of days per month would be based on the first months of the year.  Alternatively just use division and modulo to get a fixed 30 days per month or something more sane.

Comment: @maverick: 61 seconds is one minute, in case of a leap second. This is really an XY problem. Why are you trying to fit a time delta in a format that's intended for absolute time/dates?